# dnsmasq has no effect on router itself

Tags: router, dnsmasq, hosts

here is my resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver isp_provided
```

Here is my dnsmasq.conf, which will do DHCP also:

```
user=nobody
bind-dynamic
interface=br0
interface=ppp1*
no-dhcp-interface=ppp1*
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf
servers-file=/tmp/resolv.dnsmasq
no-poll
no-negcache
cache-size=1500
min-port=4096
dhcp-range=lan,192.168.5.2,192.168.5.254,255.255.255.0,86400s
dhcp-option=lan,3,192.168.5.1
dhcp-option=lan,252,"\n"
dhcp-authoritative
read-ethers
conf-dir=/tmp/mydnsmasq.d/,*.conf
```

In the `/tmp/mydnsmasq.d`, there is a `test.conf`:

```
address=/mytest/111.111.111.111
```

In the '/etc/hosts', there is an additional line:

```
111.111.111.112 mytest2
```

In clients that connected to this router, dig command can get both mytest and mytest2 address.
However, if I use nslookup command in router shell, it said "can't resolve" to mytest. OK for mytest2. 
Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: Depending on vendor nslookup may only use NIS, may or may not use hosts, etc. In theory this shouldn't matter because it should follow resolv.conf and that directs back to dnsmasq. Add your /etc/nsswitch.conf just in case and what software are you using? Openwrt?

Comment: Did you mean `nameserver 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @serge yeap, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @jdwolf Asus stock ROM. This is where I feel strange: it only follow hosts but not dnsmasq.

Comment: @Wang could you post `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from router please?

Comment: @jdwolf serge no such file at all

Comment: try to create one with a line containing `hosts:      files dns`, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html for details

Comment: @Serge does not have effect at all